# Using relationship classes in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, relationship-class

Is there any way to use relationship classes with ArcPy to access associated records?

The ArcGIS Idea for there to be [An Arcpy method for dealing with related records](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/an-arcpy-method-for-dealing-with-related-records/idi-p/967721) leads me to believe that there is not currently a solution:

> An arcpy method that notes the relationship between the two datasets
> and allows the user to pull out related records more easily would be
> helpful.  Perhaps the relationship class could be used as a parameter
> along with the two datasets since the relationship class already
> contains the logic for how the two datasets are related.

Is the only way to do this with Python to create separate loops for each feature/table?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [curtvprice](https://community.esri.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1325) in the ArcGIS Idea you linked to:

> Still miss RESELECT KEYFILE in ArcPlot which would do a similar thing.
> Select records in table 1 and migrate that selection to another table
> through a pair of key files in the source and destination table,
> regardless of 1-M,M-1,or M-N cardinality. Workflows exist in
> geoprocessing but most are clunky.
>
> Implementing this with relates would be very consistent and elegant
> and also allow the use of stored relationship classes and on the fly
> relationships created with Add Relate in Pro.

RESELECT KEYFILE was a very useful ArcInfo Workstation command.  In the absence of something similar being implemented for ArcPy I think "the only way to do this with Python [continues to be] to create separate loops for each feature/table".

I recommend that you promote the ArcGIS Idea at every opportunity.